# Load Fragment on FCM notification click using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, firebase-cloud-messaging

i'm using fcm data only message. I made some Flow to send user to destination fragment as fcm notification clicked

this is my flow

first) when the fcm message received I add pendingIntent that hold informations about destination fragment to notification builder

second) when notification clicked, it sends user to login activity to check whether user in login state or not

third) if user in login state, I send user to the destination fragment with the informations received from notification pendingIntent (MainActivity -> Fragment)

it works at first shot, but later on even though the destination is changed it only sends the user to the first destination fragment.

my log says that the login activity only receive  first destination information
but, why? please help me

```kotlin
// this is onMessageReceived, adding pendingIntent
private fun addPendingIntent(
   builder: NotificationCompat.Builder, pushIdx: Int, data: Map<String, String>) {

   val loginIntent = Intent({“LoginActivitys intent filter name”}).apply {
       flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
       putExtra("pushType", data["pushType"])
// the pushType indicate destination fragment
// in this log pushType is change as push is change
       Log.e("pushType", "${data["pushType"]}")
…
     }

 val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
   applicationContext,
   pushIdx,
   loginIntent,
   PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
)
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
}
```

```kotlin
// this is login activity
if(isLogin) {

   val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
   retrieveAndSetExtras(intent)
   startActivity(intent)
   viewModel.resetLoginState()
   this.finish()
}

private fun retrieveAndSetExtras(sendingIntent: Intent) {
// this log always print first pushType
   Log.e("LOGIN", "retrieveAndSetExtras(${this.intent.getStringExtra("pushType")})")
   this.intent.getStringExtra("pushType")?.let { pushType ->
       sendingIntent.putExtra("pushType", pushType)
       this.intent.removeExtra("pushType")
…
   }
}
```

Comment: it is because i didn't override onNewIntent callback

Comment: and also `val loginIntent = Intent({“LoginActivitys intent filter name”}) ` is problem. use activity::class.java directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After read the manual carefully, I Found right answer. This was due to the characteristics of Pendinig Intente.

I only changed the Intent extra and wanted the system to recognize it as another PendingIntent . But it doesn't work that way, so I could fix it by adding the PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT flag.

```kotlin
// this is onMessageReceived, adding pendingIntent
private fun addPendingIntent(
   builder: NotificationCompat.Builder, pushIdx: Int, data: Map<String, String>) {

   val loginIntent = Intent({“LoginActivitys intent filter name”}).apply {
       flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
       putExtra("pushType", data["pushType"])
// the pushType indicate destination fragment
// in this log pushType is change as push is change
       Log.e("pushType", "${data["pushType"]}")
…
     }

 val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
   applicationContext,
   pushIdx,
   loginIntent,
   PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
)
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
}
```

[android doc : PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent)

저 메뉴얼은 지금당장은 한글을 지원하지 않기 때문에, 한국 사람들에게는 내 블로그가 도움이 될 수도 있습니다.(Since that manual does not support Korean right now, my blog may be helpful for Koreans.)
[제 블로그입니다.](https://velog.io/@tjeong/PendingIntent-%EB%A5%BC-%EC%95%8C%EC%95%84%EB%B3%B4%EC%9E%90)

Answer (score 0):

it is because i didn't override onNewIntent callback

the LoginActivity should look like...

```kotlin
class LoginActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    ...

    private var newIntentFlag = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // init viewBinding, viewModel...
        setContentView(binding.root)

        subscribeLiveData()
        if (!newIntentFlag) {
            viewModel.checkLoginState()
        }
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(newIntent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(newIntent)
        this.intent = newIntent
        newIntentFlag = true
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (newIntentFlag) {
            viewModel.checkLoginState()
            newIntentFlag = false
        }
    }
    
    private fun subscribeLiveData() {
    // here when login state is OK -> handle intentExtras
    ...
    }

}
```

The reason I created the newIntentFlag branch in the onResume callback is because of the domain-specific characteristics. so, it is not general example